# Simplify complexity

Tags: javascript, complexity

I came across this question which asks to create a function which will return true/false based on the passed array containing all the letters to make up the passed word. Each letter from array can only be used once.

Here's my attempt:

```
const checkArray = (word, arr) => {
    let good = true
    word.split('').forEach(letter => {
        const letterIdx = arr.findIndex(arrLetter => arrLetter === letter)
        if (letterIdx === -1) good = false

        arr.splice(letterIdx, 1)
    })

    return good
}

const word = 'goal'
const arr1 = ['g', 'o','a','l','x','a','d'] // true
const arr1 = ['g', 'r','a','l','x','a','d'] // false
```

With my approach, a loop inside a loop is used. What's a better (less complexity) way of solving this issue?

Comment: Welcome!  Please edit the title of the question: [State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 8):

## appropriate names

```
const checkArray = (word, arr) => {
```

This is just a terrible signature,
almost as meaningless as `const foo = (bar, baz) ...`.

Tell the caller what's going to happen:

```
const checkWordMatchesLetters = (word, letters) => {
```

and then explain to the caller that we expect a vector of letters.

## early exit

```
        if (letterIdx === -1) good = false
```

There's no need to keep going after we encounter a missing letter.

This could just be `return false`.
In fact, there's no need for a `good` flag,
given that control flow within our function suffices.

@ggorlen helpfully points out that literally using that `return`

> unfortunately just breaks out of that iteration of the forEach callback, and the return value is ignored. Really, forEach is inappropriate here -- .every or for .. of would allow early exit.

Indeed, quite right.
I was essentially looking for an `all()` helper here.

## appropriate datastructure

```
        arr.splice(letterIdx, 1)
```

The `.findIndex()` call had linear \$O(n)\$ time complexity cost,
and asking `.splice()` to shift elements to shrink the array has similar cost.
So operating on a word of modest length
like "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
would entail hundreds of operations,
where surely only a couple dozen should suffice.
In total we have quadratic \$O(n^2)\$ cost.

Consider implementing a multiset (counter) via an `object` mapping,
from letter to count.
Linear cost to construct it,
and constant cost to verify each positive count
while decrementing each given letter's count,
adding up to a total of linear cost.

Even if you don't go that far, we could have
a better (still quadratic) algorithm by writing a
[tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming))
sentinel into an array of letters,
to show we have "used up" that particular letter.
Probably better to operate on a copy of caller's parameter,
so caller isn't surprised we trashed his array.
Going a bit further, if you invest \$O(n \log n)\$ effort in
sorting that copied array, you can enjoy \$O(\log n)\$
lookup times via binary search.

Answer (score 3):

***S*ingle *R*esponsibility *P*rinciple reduces complexity**

The `word` - function input - is cleaned of duplicate letters beforehand, allowing for a much simplified and clear "contains" function - `uniqueLetters.every`

```
const wordInAlphabet = (word, alphabet) => {
    let uniqueLetters = [...new Set(word)]
    return uniqueLetters.every(char => alphabet.includes(char))
}
```

StackOverflow References:

- [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645)
- [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104)
- [How can I process each letter of text using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1966476)

Comment: It's not clear from the problem statement that duplicates should be removed (we're missing a test case such as `"noon", "nno"`).  So perhaps we need to use multiset instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I agree that multiset ([counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)) is a requirement. I feel the problem statement was pretty clear: "_Each letter from array can only be used once._" I would definitely expect a thumbsdown result from `("noon", "nno")`. If we think about the Business Domain for this problem, it seems a fair match for manipulating [Scrabble tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble).

Comment: Yeah the idea is that duplicates are allowed but a letter is only allowed to be used once. So if the target is "grill", then [g, r, i, l] is a fail whereas [g, r, i, l, l, l] is ok

Comment: Problem statements are tricky. You go with what you got.  My code example meets the problem statement.   It tests if the alphabet-array contains the word's letters.  *Each letter from array can only be used once.*   So eliminating word-letter-duplicates meets the constraint. As for complexity - the threads theme - applied OO guidelines keeps complexity under control. If there is a larger real-world concept that may infer other requirements, well,  it is not in this problem statement.  It's all guesswork.